# Create a new dynamically named list in groovy

Tags: list, variables, dynamic, groovy

I have a list of items that looks like this `items = ["a", "b", "c"]`

I also have a list of values that looks like this `values = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", "c1", "c2", "c3"]`

my `items` list is static, but my `values` list will change often.

my code looks like this

```
for(z=0;z<items.size();z++){
    for(i=0;i<values.size();i++){
        if(values[i] =~ items[z]){
            println value[i]
        } 
    }
```

What I really want to do is add `value[i]` to a list with the name `items[z]`, something that would function like `${"items[i]"} += value[i]` and the code would read it as `a += value[1]`, `b += value[1]` so on and so forth through my loops, so at the end I could do something like this

```
assert a == ["a1", "a2", "a3"]
assert b == ["b1", "b2"]
assert c == ["c1", "c2", "c3"]
```

Is it possible to do a dynamically named variable like this?

Comment: Have you tried `Map` ? For ex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236743/map-with-key-as-string-and-value-as-list-in-groovy

Comment: I looked at using a map, and I looked into it a bit more and it could be useful down the road.  I had been working under the assumption that I could do a dynamically named variable since I can do that in java, so it was the last piece to my code. I wouldn't have to change much to do maps, so I'll look into it if I need increased functionality!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically add variables but you will need to use `this` (being the instance of the object you are setting the variable on), e.g.:

```
this."${items[i]}" += value[i]
```

This should give you what you need or at least point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I undesrtand code should be like this:

```
def map = [:]
for(z=0;z<items.size();z++){
    for(i=0;i<values.size();i++){
        if(values[i] =~ items[z]){
            if (map[values[i]] == null) {
                map[values[i]] = []
            }
            map[values[i]].add(items[z])
        } 
    }
}

assert map[values[0]] == ["a1", "a2", "a3"]
assert map[values[1]] == ["b1", "b2"]
assert map[values[2]] == ["c1", "c2", "c3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you accept the fact that the output would be a Map, here is another approach based on `each` and `findAll` closures:

```
def items = ["a", "b", "c"]
def values = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", "c1", "c2", "c3"]

def result = [:]
items.each{i->
    result.put(i, values.findAll{v->v.startsWith(i)})
}
println result; //[a:[a1, a2, a3], b:[b1, b2], c:[c1, c2, c3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`groupBy` is your friend:

```
def groups = values.groupBy { v -> 
  items.find { i -> v =~ i } 
}
assert groups.a == ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
assert groups.b == ['b1', 'b2']
assert groups.c == ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']
```

As a sidenote I'd strongly recommend you give [Groovy's excellent List/Map comprehension](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html) a thorough look; I can guarantee that once you get the idea, you'll no longer need to use for-loops in your code.